# Getting error in Passing multiple data from parent to child component in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-decorator

I am trying to send two variable from parent component to the child component. For that, I have initialized both data in an object you can see below

```js
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  myObj = {
    FirstInputString : 'Hello I am coming from Parent',
    SecondInputString :  'I am second value coming from parent'
  };
```

I have placed the child selector to the parent component view  .html file, where I used @input name myInput to bind it to the object name.

```js
<app-form-test [myInput]='myObj' (myOutput)="getData($event)"></app-form-test>
```

> But In the child component when I am using the object value .. I am
>   not able to access the key value of the defined object in the parent
>   object

```js
export class FormTestComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() myInput: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.myInput.FirstInputString);
    console.log(this.myInput.SecondInputString);
  }
}
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: there is no error shown in the console , only the data of the parent component is not shown .

Comment: I think I am not able to  bind object in the  child template properly

Comment: I am able to get the data, only one issue with your code myInput: string; instead of this you should have myInput: any;

Comment: @KirkLarkin thats what I commnted. There is nothing wrong with the code. I am getting console.log statements. Note: while building compiler will throw error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**appcomponent**

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  myObj = {
    FirstInputString : 'Hello I am coming from Parent',
    SecondInputString :  'I am second value coming from parent'
  };
```

**app component html**

```
<app-form-test [myInput]="myObj" (myOutput)="getData($event)"></app-form-test>
```

**form test component**

```
export class FormTestComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() myInput: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.myInput.FirstInputString);
    console.log(this.myInput.SecondInputString);
  }
}
```

above works perfectly fine for me.

Note: myInput: string I changed it to myInput: any, though which doesn't cause any error while running.

Please find stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8skzfj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheader%2Fheader.component.ts